# kartik-v fileinput file delete

Tags: yii2, kartik

Здрасьте, уважаемые знатоки Yii2!!! Кто может поделиться примером удаления фото из превью в виджете kartik-v fileinput? Как передать id  выбранного изображения в модель? Там где в коде вопросы не понимаю, что писать. Еще должно описываться событие JS. Споткнулся на этом, не пойму логику дальнейших действий. Спасибо!!!

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'files[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'name' => 'attachment[]',
    'language' => 'ru',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'deleteUrl' => Url::toRoute(['realty/delete-image']), //это урл экшэна.
        'initialPreview'=> $model->previewImg(), // это функция из модели для вывода фото в превью, это у меня получилось:)
        'initialPreviewConfig' => ???????????, 
        'uploadExtraData' => [
            '?????????' => ???????????,
            '????????' => ?????????????
        ],
        'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
        'overwriteInitial' => false,
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showRemove' => true,
        'showUpload' => true,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  'Добавить фото...'
    ],
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'image/*', 
        'multiple' => true,
        'maxFileCount' => 10,
        'maxFileSize'=>1000,
    ],

])?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вариант удаления картинки из превью, но и в том числе из БД я нашел следующий: `'deleteUrl' => Url::toRoute(['news/deleteimg', 'id_reshenie' => $model->id, 'id_img' => $img->id]),` а в контроллере (в моем случае NewsController) прописал:

```
public function actionDeleteimg($id_reshenie, $id_img)
    {          
         $reshenie = News::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id_reshenie])
                ->one();

        $images = $reshenie->getImages();
        foreach($images as $img){            
            if($img->id==$id_img){
                $reshenie->removeImage($img);                
            }        
        }    
        $success=true;
        return json_encode($success);
    }
```