# YII2 Вывод превью загруженных изображений в FileInput Widget

Tags: yii2, виджет, kartik

Всем здравствуйте!Использую на сайте виджет FileInput Widget, при редактировании материала мне необходимо чтобы в виджете отображались фотографии которые уже загружены на сервер к текущему материалу. Изображения я загружаю через виджет CostaRico/yii2-images, если я обращаюсь напрямую к `$model->getImages(),` то выводятся просто пустые блоки Object в том количестве сколько у меня фото к материалу (как на скрине).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предыдущий вариант который я пытался использовать это вывод изображений через foreach, но данный метод не подошел, т.к. в таком случае изображения выводились, но получалось что они находились все в одном блоке, а не по раздельности.

```
<?php
$gallery = $model->getImages();
$gal_img = '';
foreach ($gallery as $images) {
    $gal_img .= Html::img('http://bolkolledg2.loc/web/upload/store/' . Html::encode($images->filePath), ['alt' => $images->filePath, 'style' => 'width:auto;height:auto;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;']);
}
?>
```

Здесь на сайте уже был подобный вопрос, но он касался удаления превью изображений [kartik-v fileinput file delete](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829261/kartik-v-fileinput-file-delete/849840?noredirect=1#comment1367529_849840), но там автор сам прописал какую-то функцию в модели для вывода изображений превью `'initialPreview'=> $model->previewImg()`, у меня же функцию написать не получается

Comment: Может быть стоит попробовать переопределить модель и необходимый метод?

Comment: Я с YII2 не так давно работаю, можно поподробнее? Если Вы имеете в виду переопределить саму функцию getImages(), то думаю это не вариант, т.к. эта функция прописана к виджету CostaRico/yii2-images и на сайте используется достаточно часто в разных местах.

Comment: Создайте свой класс виджета, унаследуйте его от CostaRico, скопируйте необходимый метод и переделайте его под свои нужды. Вместо CostaRico используйте свой виджет.